# How to config mysql with django and phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using django for my backend and mysql for database on nginx webserver on digitalocean. I want to use phpmyadmin to manipulate my database. Is there a way to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think your question has got anything to do with Django. All you need to do is configure phpmyadmin to connect with your mysql server. I'm removing the Django tag.

Comment: @xyres I would like to connect django with phpmyadmin, did you know resources or guide to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Install phpmyadmin and manipulate the database however you want. You can setup Django to use the existing database from there.

Comment: hi thanks for reply, My goal here is http://example.com/ → to serve Django App and http://example.com/phpmyadmin → to serve phpmyadmin. I have installed phpmyadmin on my vps. How do i configure nginx to server to get phpmyadmin on http://example.com/phpmyadmin